# Getting the C++ compiler to reveal what a type can be converted to

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

Below is a flawed (and simplified) template function that expects to work on a template arg that can be converted to one of a predefined number of types.

It happens to be 2 types, but it cold be many more.

```
void do_something_type_specific( const int &unused ) { std::cout << 'i'; }
void do_something_type_specific( const std::string &unused ) { std::cout << 's'; }

template< typename Iterator >
void perform_work_on_a_range( Iterator begin, Iterator end )
{
    do_something_type_specific( *begin );
    // Perhaps more code...
}
```

This happens to produce the desired results in my environment.
Template instances will compile successfully iff `*Iterator` produces a type that's convertible to exactly one of the choices.

However, this code unnecessarily requests that the conversion be performed and, despite `unused` being unused, there is still UB when `begin == end`.

How can this this behavior be implemented in C++03 without these problems?

Comment: I think it could probably be done with SFINAE.

Comment: As far as I know, C++03 only provides a "simple" runtime, where there is no way to see what a type can be converted to. It is a static language, apart from a little runtime-polymorphism.

Comment: @bash.d what a type can be converted to is static information (remember, C++ is a static language!). I don't see why runtime would be involved in that.

Comment: @bash.d: But he takes the type as a template parameter, so he can.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://liveworkspace.org/code/3A44Ws$7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of dereferencing the iterator that my result in undefined behaviour when `begin == end`, you could try using [std::iterator_traits<>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits). E.g.:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

void do_something_type_specific(std::string const&) { printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }
void do_something_type_specific(int const&) { printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__); }

template<class T>
struct ProduceValue
{
    static T value;
};

template<class T>
T ProduceValue<T>::value;

// Specializations for types that can't be default constructed or must be initialized.
template<>
char* ProduceValue<char*>::value = "";

template< typename Iterator >
void perform_work_on_a_range( Iterator begin, Iterator end )
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;
    do_something_type_specific(ProduceValue<value_type>::value);
}

int main() {
    char** p = 0;
    perform_work_on_a_range(p, p);

    long* q = 0;
    perform_work_on_a_range(q, q);
}
```

Output:

```
void do_something_type_specific(const string&)
void do_something_type_specific(const int&)
```

The only inconvenience is that `ProduceValue<T>` has to be specialized for types that can't be default constructed or must be initialized for other reasons (like `char*`).

Comment: I'm an expert, and even I can't figure out how you could possibly use this to avoid UB.

Comment: @DeadMG you basically just put your expert title on the line, like all in )

Comment: @DeadMG you could, for instance, use `iterator_traits<>::value_type` together with `boost::is_convertible` to write a meta function to determine whether the value type is convertible instead of dereferencing the iterator. Or maybe call a function with a `(value_type *)0` pointer.

Comment: @DeadMG You'd use `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type` to call the appropriate type-specific function.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I can assist your answer if you don't know) What can be done with iterators like `std::back_inserter`, whose value_type would be `void` here?

Comment: @DrewDormann You could declare specialization `template<>  struct ProduceValue<void>;` but not define it, that would stop it from compiling when `value_type` is `void`. This function, though, probably expects input iterators, not output... Thinking more, it should have difficulty instantiating `void ... value;` anyway.

Comment: @dhavenith I suspect a really clean answer could come out of your `is_convertible` idea.  I may take a shot at an answer later... I want to let the dust settle in case someone's typing it up now.

Comment: @DeadMG are you saying that you've spotted UB in this answer?  Or that you can't figure out if there's UB?

Comment: What I mean is the iterator traits have not helped you at all. You have drastically changed the functionality by *not using the object from the range at all*, and instead are using some random awful global variable instead. Instead of UB, you've just done something useless. Also, since I suggested is_convertible in my own answer, I already know of it.

Comment: @DeadMG _drastically changed functionality_ - the target function does not use the argument, so what is wrong with passing any value of that type? _using some random awful global variable instead_ - as long as it does not affect how other parts of the program operate, what is wrong with that on practice please?

Comment: @DeadMG Thanks for your input.  I didn't mean for this question to upset anyone.  I understand that you want some object from the range to get used, but that's not germane to the question posed here.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `boost::is_convertible` metafunction that you can use to determine if a type T can be converted to some other type U.

Secondly, for `begin == end`, just insert a run-time check.

Comment: "for begin == end, just insert a run-time check" that would change the behavior, wouldn't it?  Which `do_something_type_specific` should be called then?

Comment: @DrewDormann: You requested that it didn't have UB when `begin == end`. That's changing the behaviour. So it meets the requirements. You can't know if `begin == end` without checking.

Comment: Which `do_something_type_specific()` should be called in that circumstance?

Comment: @DrewDormann: How the hell should I know? Defining the semantics of this function for the empty range are your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problematic code in the question is trying to leverage features of both *template parameters* and *function parameters*.

Function parameters allow type conversions, but require an instantiation of the type.  Template parameters don't need instantiation, but also don't perform type conversions.

The pattern below uses Boost's [`enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) and [`is_convertible`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_convertible.html) to allow *template functions to be chosen by the compiler as if template parameters supported the same type conversion rules as function parameters.*  (Thank @dhavenith for the suggestion)

```
#include <boost/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

// enable_if_c makes the return type either void or a Substitution Failure.
template < typename T>
typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_convertible<T,int>::value>::type
do_something_type_specific()
{
  std::cout << 'i';
}

template < typename T>
typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_convertible<T,std::string>::value>::type
do_something_type_specific()
{
  std::cout << 's';
}

template< typename Iterator >
void perform_work_on_a_range( Iterator begin, Iterator end )
{
    // This code is from @MaximYegorushkin's answer.  Vote him up :)
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;
    do_something_type_specific<value_type>();
    // Perhaps more code...
}
```

This has been verified with @MaximYegorushkin's sample main.

```
int main() {
    char** p = 0;
    perform_work_on_a_range(p, p);

    long* q = 0;
    perform_work_on_a_range(q, q);
}
```

Output:

```
si
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
template <typename T>
void do_something_type_specific() {}
template <>
void do_something_type_specific<int>() {...}
template <typename Iterator>
void perform_work_on_a_range(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    do_something_type_specific<typename Iterator::value_type>();
}
```

Comment: If `Iterator::value_type` is say `short` that should call `int` version because `short` is convertible to `int`.